# Converting map[string]interface{} to valid Mongo query

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, bson

I am currently receiving a mongo aggregate query from a payload:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "isComplete": true
      "accountId": "foo123"
      "startTime": "2017-03-06T23:07:21.262Z"
      "$or": [ { userId: "bar123" }, { userId: "bar235" } ]
    } 
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is being stored as a `map[string]interface{}`. The issue is the `$match` clause can be any arbitrary query, which means it can contain ObjectIds and Dates. I have tried manually converting ids to `bson.ObejectId`s and any Dates to `time.Times` but the queries can become very complicated.

Does anyone know any good way of taking an arbitrary mongo query from a payload and converting it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to unmarshaling to a `[]map[string]interface{}` with that array structure in the post.

With that being said you can do something like this (with the currect `map[string]interface{}` type.

```
type Payload struct {
    Message map[string]interface{} `json:"message"`
}

// If you are using it as a http HandleFunc
func (s *Server) ProcessPayload() {
    PayloadHandler := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        incoming := r.FormValue("message")
        if incoming != "" {
            var payload = new(Payload)
            json.Unmarshal([]byte(incoming), payload)

            go payload.FromPayload()
        }
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/payload", PayloadHandler)
}

func (p *Payload) FromPayload() {
    match, ok := p.Message["$match"]
    if !ok {
        return
    }
    // Do your work on the $match object
}
```

Comment: I'd have to know more about the problems you are facing when handling the dynamic structure of the `$match` object.